# how to get "logId" in Azure SpeechSDK

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, azure-speech

I'm using azure speech to text realtime by microphone,and I want to get the audio file when the talk finished.
i find this API [Get Custom Model Endpoint Log](https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/GetEndpointLog)
can get the file,
but how to get the logId?

I have try to find it in doc but nothing,

```
speechConfig.enableAudioLogging();
```

set this but nothing change in log.

Comment: you can list all the logs with get endpoint logs

Answer (score 0):

Regarding speechConfig.enableAudioLogging(), this just tells the service to turn on server-side audio logging. I think there also needs to be a setting in your Azure speech portal for your custom model, to enable logging. Both need to be set.